# UICollectionView setup with multiple sections in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

[image]

This is the layout that I am working towards and that I have finished setting up Section 1 which is represented by the black border. I want to be able to layout my multiple cells and sections in the storyboard instead of using code, is that possible?

I am having difficulty setting up section 2, which is represented by the blue borders alongside with section 1, which have different layouts.

Is my approach to setting up the layout to be like that wrowng? If so some guidance would be appreciated!

My storyboard (UICollectionView Controller)
[image]

Comment: http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/

Answer (score 1):

To support above layout, can make maintain a UITableview with various section title and UICollectionview inside each UITableviewCell to have horizontal scrolling layout.
Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i am geussing that will  not work
Becuase scrolling is set to be horizontal as a collectionview
The best and easiest is  to nest collectionview in tableview
That mean you have mutipls collectionviews  horizontal scrolling in one viewcontroller
Edit 
The code is in the comment

```
  class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell{


    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
       // super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


}

    extension TableViewCell

{

    func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate
        <D: UICollectionView  & UICollectionViewDataSource>
        (_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row:Int)
    {
        collection.delegate = dataSourceDelegate as! UICollectionViewDelegate 
        collection.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        collection.reloadData()
    }

}
```

the view controller

```
UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDelegate {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "maincell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.title.text = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.collection.tag = indexPath.row
        //collection  is the collection view 
//tag is important so you assign the cell to the specific in the collection viewcellforitem
        cell.collection.reloadData()
        return cell
    }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView.tag == 0 {
// this is a collection view and it will be loaded in table view cell zero
       return     self.main1.count       

    }else {
return self.anotherarray.count }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "sidecell", for: indexPath) as! Collection2
        if collectionView.tag == 0 {
 //belongs to tableview cell index 0 
            cell.title.text = self.main1[indexPath.row].Des
            }

        }
```

Comment: That should be a comment.

Answer (score -2):

My approach to solve this was to create a new UIViewController and insert in the UICollectionViews that I need and then set the datasource and delegate accordingly.